# Timer in Today Extension Freezes Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, widget

I have a timer to a date counting down in my today widget. I am gathering the date from my View Controller and then starting a timer in the extension and from there I am displaying the dates in three labels, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds. In my app... this is perfect, but not so true in the notification center. The countdown loads correctly and works great for about 20 seconds. After that it skips a second and freezes, then it starts again in about 4 seconds and then it will reset the whole widget (everything disappears) and then about 2 seconds later the whole widget resets. Is this a memory warning or something?

View Controller:
 mainTextLabel.text = 436496400

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.nicmac.nextgame"];

        [sharedDefaults setObject:mainTextLabel.text forKey:@"MyNumberKey"];
        [sharedDefaults synchronize];
```

Today View Controller

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(userDefaultsDidChange:)
                                                     name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 300);

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateNumberLabelText) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];


}

- (void)userDefaultsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateNumberLabelText) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}

- (void)updateNumberLabelText {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.nicmac.nextgame"];
    NSString *date = [defaults stringForKey:@"MyNumberKey"];
    self.numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date];


    NSString *doubleString = self.numberLabel.text;
    double value = [doubleString doubleValue];

    destinationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:value];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateNumberLabelText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    int units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:destinationDate options:0];


    [hour setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[components day] * 24 + (long)[components hour]]];
    [minute setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[components minute]]];
    [second setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[components second]]];

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here lies in the `- (void)updateNumberLabelText` method. 
Specifically, here:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateNumberLabelText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

This means that every time you're calling this method, it's scheduling **another** timer to call this method every second (every second because `repeats:YES`). That means, every second (with a micro offset because of any lag in the computer), x number of scheduled timers is producing x MORE number of scheduled timers, meaning that every second you have double the number of timers. This is called exponential growth, and can be modelled to `2^x`.

So to find the number of timers in 20 seconds:

> ```
> 2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6+2^7+2^8+2^9+2^10+2^11+2^12+2^13+2^14+2^15+2^16+2^17+2^18+2^19+2^20
> ```

Ew, can we represent this better - **we can!** We can use sigma notation like so:

> ```
>  <no. of seconds>
> Σ    2^i
>  i=1
> ```

But enough math. That averages out to around a whopping **2,000,000** timers initialised in 20 seconds. That is a **lot** of timers, and the widget eventually struggles to catch breath (no more memory!) and dies/crashes/restarts itself.

Here's how to fix it:
If you really want this method to loop itself, call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(updateNumberLabelText) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

in the method instead.

You could do it the way you're currently doing it and do `repeats:NO` instead, but I don't think that the timer will `invalidate` itself after the 1.0 second, and creating that many timers is not very efficient.